# Have a question on this sentence 「ていうか、今日めっちゃ寒くね。」

Tags: grammar

ていうか、今日めっちゃ寒くね。
Today I've met this sentence and got confused. Why the sentence used 寒くinstead of using 寒い?Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very casual phrase, which is used by a part of teenagers or 20s.
寒くね。 means "寒くない？" or "寒くないか？" (It is chilly, isn't it?)

> やばくね！？　= やばくないか！？ (It is awful/incredible/awesome/terrible/too bad/..., isn't it!?)
> いけたくね？ = いけたんじゃないか？ (It worked well, doesn't it!?)

寒くないか？｛samukunaika?}　→　寒くない？｛samukunai?}　→　寒くね？{samukune?}

Speak "kunai" as fast as possible. It should be the almost same sound as "kune".
That's why they use "くね？".

Again, this is very casual and I think even many teenagers or 20s don't use it.
Most uses "くない？" like "寒くない？" when they talk casually.